# Cascading dropdown doesn't load on page load

Tags: html, vue.js, axios, frontend

I am using VueJS to have a front-end application.

i have made a Vue-Component, that component has 2 dropdown's, the 2nd dropdown depends on the item selected in the first dropdown.
I am using axios to fetch the values that should be shown in the second dropdown.
this i manage to get it working with vueJS, but the main issue is when i load the page.

So when i load the page i want the user to be able what is chosen, so the first dropdown needs to get the value from the DB and the second dropdown also needs to get the value from the DB.

there i think, it goes wrong.

When the first value is set on loading the page, the data list for the dropdown is not fetched or is fechted too late. thus the second dropdown is not set to the value on load of the component, how can i fix this? in any case i don't know what i should do with the issue.

Comment: i've tried playing around with the loaded, mounted, and all the other lifecycle events from the vue object. but no luck so far to get a working one.

Comment: it's going to be difficult to troubleshoot without seeing any code...